# Leafing through the pages with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope you could help me to solve the problem.

Fundamentally, I have a 'main' div with two arrow-like images. Clicking on the images, I have to be able to replace the content of the 'main' div with the content of the 'main' div of another .html page, creating the 'illusion' that you are leafing through the pages.

Here is my *.html* and *.js* code:

**HTML**

PAGE1

```
<div id="main">

<div id="noMainVarOnLoad">
<!-- CONTENT OF THE DIV -->
<img src="img/scroll_right.png" class="scroll_page_buttons" id="scroll_page_right" data-nextpage="page2.html">
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="application/javascript"><\/script>')</script> 

<script type="application/javascript" src="etheric_injection.js"></script>
```

PAGE2

```
<div id="main">

<div id="noMainVarOnLoad">
<!-- CONTENT OF THE DIV -->
<img src="img/scroll_right.png" class="scroll_page_buttons" id="scroll_page_right" data-nextpage="page3.html">
<img src="img/scroll_left.png" class="scroll_page_buttons" id="scroll_page_left" data-previouspage="page1.html">
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="application/javascript"><\/script>')</script> 

<script type="application/javascript" src="etheric_injection.js"></script>
```

PAGE_3

```
<div id="main">

<div id="noMainVarOnLoad">
<!-- CONTENT OF THE DIV -->
<img src="img/scroll_left.png" class="scroll_page_buttons" id="scroll_page_left" style="border: 1px solid blue" data-previouspage="page2.html">  

</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script> 
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="application/javascript"><\/script>')</script> 

<script type="application/javascript" src="etheric_injection.js"></script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var $j=jQuery.noConflict();

$j("#scroll_page_right").on("click",function(e){
var getData=$j("#scroll_page_right").data("nextpage");

$j("#noMainVarOnLoad").load(getData+" #noMainVarOnLoad");
e.preventDefault(); 

});

$j("#scroll_page_left").on("click",function(e){
var getData=$j("#scroll_page_left").data("previouspage");

$j("#noMainVarOnLoad").load(getData+" #noMainVarOnLoad");
e.preventDefault(); 

});
```

So, what is the problem? Let's consider the case I am on *page2.html*. Clicking on the images, I successfully succeed to replace, for example, the content of page2.html's 'main' div with the content of page1.html's 'main' div.

So, now I am on my page2.html and have the 'main' content of page2 replaced with the content of page1.html (as you can see from the code, the 'main' div of page1.html has, differently from page2.html, the right-arrow-like image only).

After that, if I re-click now on the right-arrow-like image to replace the actual content - which is the page1.html's one - with the content of page2.html, nothing happens.

I spent several days trying to figuring out what the problem could be, but I found no solution.

Comment: if `etheric_injection.js` contain that code, that you have written, it would be executed each time you are navigating pages. So you kinda need 1 main 'container' page, which would hold all scripts and other - 'content' pages, which dont

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @IvanShmidt :-) 

So, how would you restructure the html/js code?

Comment: `index.html`, in which you'll have your `<script type="application/javascript" src="etheric_injection.js"></script> ` and `<div id="main"></div>` tags. Then pages 1-3 without the 'main' div, just straight content. Also pages 1-3 does **not** contain script tags. So pretty much of a simple templating system, try looking into _Handlebars_

Comment: I've been doing lots of tests during the last days and finally I've found a solution.

I put the straight content of the pages in external .txt files along with their respective <script> tags* and adjusted a bit the javascript code posted above.

* I tried to not include the <script> tags as you suggested; however, in this way the code does not work.